# How to make a userInput field react when anykey pressed?

Tags: android

Im new to android development and i am working for a start screen where to user will type a code and if the code is correct a hidden confirm button will become visible.

I have been looking for a command that will check if any keyboard key is pressed, but i haven't found anything.

Any idea what i should use to check for any key being pressed?

Comment: What have u done

Comment: I mean what all have you done so far

Answer (score 0):

May be this will helpfull for you
Use TextWatcher in android

```
EditText input;
```

then add listener to it

```
input.addTextChangedListener(watch);
```

Now, do this

```
TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher(){

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    output.setText(s);
    if(start == 9){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maximum Limit Reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}};
```

Comment: Looks promising, but can it be used compare to a string value like "test" ?

Comment: Yes, you can compare it

a) In @Override method  onTextChanged ==> compare string using variable "s",

b) Or you can get string in any method by 
     String message = editText.getText().toString()